# react native DatePickerIOS disable minutes or show only hours

Tags: ios, react-native, datepicker

In my app (built using react native) I want to show a timer where users can select time every hour of the date using the `DatePickerIOS`

ex:

01-01-2018 00:00 AM
01-01-2018 01:00 AM
01-01-2018 02:00 AM
.
.
.
01-01-2018 10:00 PM
01-01-2018 21:00 PM

currently the maximum `minuteInterval` I can set is `enum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30)`

Is there a way to set to minute interval to 60 or disable the time part of this component?

I dont want to write a custom component only for this.